# How do I get access to existing icons from other components from a VS package?

Tags: visual-studio, vspackage, vsip

I have a Visual Studio package, and I want to display the VS snippets icon - how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I needed to use `IGlyphService` passing in `StandardGlyphGroup.GlyphCSharpExpansion` and `StandardGlyphItem.GlyphItemPublic`. This gets me back the standard "scissors" icon for snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Visual Studio icons from the [Visual Studio Image Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825). Simply search for snippet to find the snippet icons (sometimes it is quite hard to find a specific icon).

This icons can be freely used AFAIK. The only restriction is, that the have to be used the way they are intended to be used (don't use a delete icon for a menu item that triggers a create operation etc.)